# jQuery error preventing imageMapper from working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with a script from a third party not working. The error I get is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).imageMapper is not a function"

I have tried to fix this a few times, nothing seems to work. Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated. Below is the script:

```js
(function() {
  var mapper_63_loadScript = function(url, success) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      done = false;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
        done = true;
        success();
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        head.removeChild(script);
      }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
  };

  var mapper_63_execute_scripts = function() {
    jQuery('.imagemapper63-wrapper').imageMapper({
      itemOpenStyle: 'click',
      itemDesignStyle: 'responsive',
      responsiveWidth: 600,
      transformSmall: 1,
      oldResponsive: 0,
      animateOther: 1000,
      pinScalingCoefficient: 1,
      advancedPinOptions: true,
      pinClickAction: "content",
      pinHoverAction: "my_content",
      useTransitions: '1',
      animationDuration: 170,
      mapOverlay: true
    });
  };

  if ((typeof jQuery === 'undefined') || (parseInt(jQuery.fn.jquery) === 1 && parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery.replace(/^1\./, "")) < 9.1)) {
    mapper_63_loadScript('//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', function() {
      mapper_63_loadScript('https://easy-image-mapper.herokuapp.com/shopify_image_mapper.js?shop=mustaevusa.myshopify.com', function() {
        mapper_63_execute_scripts();
      });
    });
  } else {
    mapper_63_loadScript('https://easy-image-mapper.herokuapp.com/shopify_image_mapper.js?shop=mustaevusa.myshopify.com', function() {
      mapper_63_execute_scripts();
    });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `mapper_63_execute_scripts();` to inside your readystate handler at line 7.

You are attempting to call that code prior to it being available in the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, while that did eliminate the error, the content on the page does not load.